# Asp.Net Web API is not receiving Post data from angular

Tags: c#, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Please help me out.

I want to pass string to Post method of WebApi controller using $http method.But I am getting null string at controller side.

Here is my client side code.

```
$http({
        url: 'http://localhost/MyWebApi/api/home',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
        data: JSON.stringify({name: $scope.newProduct})

    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.products = data;
        $scope.newProduct = "";
        console.log(data);
    })
     .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {         
         console.log(data);
      });
```

And here is my WebApi controller

```
 [HttpPost]
        public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]string newProduct)
        {
            var db = new MVCEntities();
            db.Products.Add(new Product() { ProductName = newProduct });
            db.SaveChanges();
            var products = db.Products.ToList();
            return Ok();
        }
```

Thanks

Comment: try replace name with newProduct inside JSON.stringify({name: $scope.newProduct})

Answer (score 2):

You are getting null probably because your POST request doesn't match your method signature: Try this:

```
data: { newProduct: $scope.newProduct }
```

If it still doesn't work, try also removing the `[FromBody]` attribute from your controller:

```
public IHttpActionResult Post(string newProduct)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON does not match the method signature. There is no need for JSON, you can pass it in as normal string

```
data: $scope.newProduct
```

**Or** use a custom object, that matches your JSON and use it as parameter for your method, like

```
[DataContract]
public class NewProductData{

   [DataMember(Name="name")]
   public string Name {get;set;}
}
```

New method signature

```
public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]NewProductData newProduct)
```

Comment: I tried this but it is not working.I'm still getting null

Comment: @Hirma Try Using content-type "text/plain" if using my first approach